# Error with Angular Material sidenav: cannot read property of undefined

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I'm working on an Angular client app and I've already used few of Material's features in this app like dialog, select, card etc. I think I've already installed everything I need. Now I made a sidenav and I want to use material's sidenav module, so I made it like this:

```html
<mat-container>
  <mat-content>
    <div (click)="sidenav.toggle()"></div>
    my component html . . .
  </mat-content>
  <mat-sidenav #sidenav>
    <app-sidenav></app-sidenav>
  </mat-sidenav>
</mat-container>
```

Now when I'm navigating to this component I'm getting an error:

> Uncaught (in promise):TypeError: Cannot read property 'runOutsideAngular' of undefined

Without the  the component works perfectly fine... Does anybody know what might be the problem?
Thanks!

Comment: Can you show code of your component?

Comment: https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/10567

Comment: @Agney Issue us closed, but problem not solved.

Comment: @Dormouse Well, closed due to inactivity. Guess they did not solve it anyway

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I did it almost thesame code but changed these as followed:

- `<mat-container>          =>          <mat-drawer-container>`
- `<mat-content>            =>          <mat-drawer-content>`
- `<mat-sidenav #sidenav>  =>           <mat-drawer #drawer>`

Comment: how did you find out what was the cause of this?

Comment: It's amazing that even with Angular 10 this is still an issue 

Answer (score 2):

I encountered the same error when running `ng test` on [Angular Material's Navigation Schematic](https://material.angular.io/guide/schematics#navigation-schematic):

`ng generate @angular/material:material-nav --name <component-name>`

I fixed the issue by changing `mat-sidenav` to `mat-drawer` in the `mat-navbar-test.component.html`.

Answer (score 1):

Before

```
<mat-sidenav-container *ngIf="currentAdmin && currentAdmin.role" id="nav" >
```

I encountered this issue and solved it by removing *ngIf on the parent, 'mat-sidenav-container'

```
<mat-sidenav-container id="nav" >
```

Answer (score 0):

i made sidenav like this and its working properly, try this.

```html
<mat-container>
  <mat-content>
    <div (click)="sidenav.toggle()">
  my component html . . .
 </div>
  </mat-content>
  </mat-container>
  <mat-sidenav-container>
    <mat-sidenav #sidenav>
  <app-sidenav></app-sidenav>
 </mat-sidenav>
</mat-sidenav-container>
```

Comment: 1. the component code is a lot of is a lot of html & other functions its really doesn't matter. In the module I imported my shared module which imported my material module
2. if this is really the issue like they are saying in the github link that is also a problem cause i can't change the target to es2015